# make a field required based on the selected response in drop down field using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

This is my first time working with jQuery and I desperately need some help.

I have a form on a visualforce page (Salesforce) that I am trying to validate using the jQuery validate plugin. I have some fields that are hidden unless the user selects "Yes" from a dropdown box. The new fields ask for more details and should be required when they are rendered.

The problem is, I don't know how to write the function to return true when the dropdown is "Yes"

I have tried this with no success:

```
j$('[id$=newDGRecord]').validate();     
j$('[id$=InsuranceHistory]').rules("add",{
                required: true
            });

j$('[id$=insuranceRiskHistory]').rules("add",{
                required: function() {
                  return j$('[id$=InsuranceHistory]').val() == "Yes";
                    }
                });
```

The relavent visual force markup is:

```
<div class="form-group required">
                                <apex:outputLabel value="Insurance History" for="InsuranceHistory" styleClass="control-label col-sm-2" />
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <apex:outputText >
                                        <p>Have you, your business, or anyone else named on this form ever had insurance declined, cancelled or refused? </p>
                                    </apex:outputText>
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!Dumping_Grounds__c.Insurance_Declined_or_Cancelled__c}" styleClass="form-control" id="InsuranceHistory" >
                                      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="insurancepanel"/>
                                    </apex:inputField>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <apex:outputPanel id="insurancepanel">
                                  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(Dumping_Grounds__c.Insurance_Declined_or_Cancelled__c = 'Yes', true,false)}" id="insuranceRisk">
                                      <apex:outputLabel value="More Details" styleClass="control-label col-sm-2" for="insuranceRiskHistory"/>
                                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <p>Please provide additional details.</p>
                                        <apex:inputField value="{!Dumping_Grounds__c.Insurance_History__c}" styleClass="form-control" id="insuranceRiskHistory"/>
                                      </div>
                                   </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
```

Could anyone help me with this? It seems so simple, but I am lost.

Comment: Show all _relevant_ HTML markup along with your `.validate()` method.

Comment: I am using the jQuery validate plugin

Comment: I know you're using the jQuery Validate plugin.  We do not need to see the Visual Force markup you have on the server... we only need to see the ***rendered*** markup that's sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "ends with" selector, `$=` ...

```
j$('[id$=InsuranceHistory]')
```

Therefore, your selector potentially contains more than one item.

However, with the jQuery Validate plugin, its methods are only applied to the *first* item in the group.  So you'll need to use an `.each()` to apply the method to all items...

```
j$('[id$=InsuranceHistory]').each(function() {
    j$(this).rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
});
```

---

> *"I don't know how to write the function to return true when the dropdown is 'Yes'"*

You would write a function using [the `depends` property](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules).

```
required: {
    depends: function(element) { // element is the object being evaluated
        // your conditional
        // return true to activate the 'required' rule
    }
}
```

I cannot see your HTML markup and don't know why you're using the "ends with" selector on everything, so it's impossible for me to construct the exact working code.

I am also not sure why you're using the `.rules('add')` method to declare rules.  Where is your `.validate()` method and why can't you use it?

Comment: I edited my original post with the rest of the code. I used $= because it was used in this example and was working up to this point: http://th3silverlining.com/2010/03/02/visualforce-form-validation-enhanced/

Comment: @thenichelle, without explaining the need for `$=`, that's not a very good tutorial.  Please review the basic examples in [the tag wiki for this plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) and browse some of [the code examples used within these SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate).